# Error: Cannot interpret '0' as a data type

Tags: python, numpy, random

I wrote the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal

N = 100
x_zeros = np.random.Generator.multivariate_normal(mean=np.array((1, 1)), cov=0.1*np.array((2,0),(0,2)), size=(N/2,))
```

I get the following error and nothing I have tried fixes it.

```plaintext
Cannot interpret '0' as a data type
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Your problem is with `cov = 0.1 * np.array((2,0),(0,2))`. The first argument is `(2,0)` and is interpreted as the "array_like object", and `(0,2)` becomes the second argument which is interpreted as the optional `dtype`. Put parentheses around those two elements to create your covariance matrix:

```
cov = 0.1 * np.array(((2,0),(0,2)))
```

In general, consider using the strategy of breaking down complex statements into separate pieces to home in on where the problem lies. There's no real benefit to putting everything into a complex one-liner.